# Variables from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple div:

```
<div id='names'>
    name1[John]
    name2[Blake]
    name3[Sven]
    name4[Ellis]
</div>
```

And I want to return these variables using JavaScript

```
var name1 = "John";
var name2 = "Blake";
var name3 = "Sven";
var name4 = "Ellis";
```

Comment: So what JavaScript have you tried? You need to show a little effort.

Comment: you want them as separate vars or an array???

Comment: This question makes no sense, you want to return these variables with JS ? what does that mean ? what do you think does it means ?

Comment: Do you want to parse the html into js ?

Comment: Look at `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Theses are the standard for String-To-JavaScript and JavaScript-To-String operations

Comment: Should do this at the source that creates that text. Question is really lacking in proper details or any attempt to solve problem whatsoever

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen there is no json in that text

Comment: So read the html, generate a regular expression that matches the pattern, loop over the matches, generate the variables.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see why your question was voted down and will be closed

Comment: Just for fun: `var text = document.getElementById("names").innerHTML;
var JSONVar = "{"+ text.replace(/\[/g,":\"").replace(/\]/g,"\",").slice(0,-2)+"}"; 
eval("var js="+JSONVar);
console.log(JSON.stringify(js))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks a lot of detail. Can there be more than those four names? Can't you restructure your code to get an easier access to the data?

```
var toParse = document.getElementById('names').innerHTML;
var m;
var re = /\[(.*)\]/g;

while (m = re.exec(toParse)) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/hL4bu5j1/)

This code looks for text in [Bracers] and outputs it to the console to give you an idea how you could approach this. You should be good to go with that. Wanted to put this as a comment but I'm not yet allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
//document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='names'>\n    name1[John]\n    name2[Blake]\n    name3[Sven]\n    name4[Ellis]\n</div";
var obj = {};
var str = document.getElementById("names").innerHTML;
while(str.lastIndexOf(' ') >= 0) {
  str=str.replace(' ','')
}
var str=str.split("\n");
for(var i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
  if(str[i].length > 2) {
    obj[str[i].replace(']','').split('[')[0]] = str[i].replace(']','').split('[')[1];
  }
}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an ugly version :

```
var divContent = document.getElementById('names').innerHTML;

var array = divContent.trim().split(" ").filter(removeEmpty);
console.log(array)
var name1 = array[0].split('1')[1];
```

I think Regex suits better for your issue

https://jsfiddle.net/hrgk2s1u/